# Error when importing csv into MySQL With Python

Tags: python, mysql, csv, import

Hi I have only just started with Python,

I have written this .py file with a simple test and has worked fine but when I just simply added more %s's it bomb's out with:

Error:
`File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 159, in execute query = query % db.literal(args) TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`

Python Script:

---

```
import csv
 import MySQLdb

  mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='******',
    db='kestrel_keep')

cursor = mydb.cursor()

csv_data = csv.reader(file('data_csv.log'))

for row in csv_data:

        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO `heating` VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,)',
       row)
#close the connection to the database.
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
import os


print "Done"
```

---

CSV File Format:

```
2013-02-21,21:42:00,-1.0,45.8,27.6,17.3,14.1,22.3,21.1,1,1,2,2
2013-02-21,21:48:00,-1.0,45.8,27.5,17.3,13.9,22.3,20.9,1,1,2,2
```

Any Ideas??

Thanks.

Comment: You have 14 '%s' placeholders in the call to `cursor.execute`, but each row of your sample CSV file has only 13 items.  That might be a good place to start.

Comment: yes when I remove the last one I get a column count error???

Comment: How many columns are in the heating table of your database?  You can find that out by running the `mysql` command-line client, and executing the statement `DESC heating`.

Comment: Thank You So Much Adam I can't believe I missed that???? Simplistic things hey!!! Just needed another set Of Eye's I suppose!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Check and Check  Again!!

I had diffident no.s of fields..

I.e. I if you get the above error it is normally because your csv has different amount to the %s place holders. you will get a column count error when there is a difference in you mysql table columns.

Thank You Adam Mihalcin for helping point this out!